# Some questions about `ngx_palloc`?

Tags: c, nginx

In nginx, a pointer initial by `ngx_pcalloc()` make sure that the lowest 2 bit is `00`?

For example, `p = ngx_pcalloc(pool, size)`, make sure `((uintptr_t)p)&(0x3) == 0` ?

I will appreciate it if you help me.

Comment: don't put links to show the code. Put the relevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `ngx_pcalloc` is in [ngx_palloc.c](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/59c34b67952c2ebee6760ca3115ba19e65060b58/src/core/ngx_palloc.c) so you can follow its calls to see that it returns memory aligned to `NGX_ALIGNMENT`.

On most platforms, [`NGX_ALIGNMENT` is defined](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/59c34b67952c2ebee6760ca3115ba19e65060b58/src/core/ngx_config.h#L97) as the size of an `unsigned long`. Solaris appears to be the exception: there it is defined as `_MAX_ALIGNMENT` which is ["Equal to the maximum of all the above _XXX_ALIGNMENT values"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5173/types.h-3head/index.html) which includes the alignment for unsigned longs.

The C standard requires `unsigned long` to have a minimum size of 32 bits (4 bytes). Hence the returned pointer value must be a multiple of 4, and the lower two bits (representing the values 1 and 2) will always be zero.

Answer (score 1):

> how to make sure that the low 2 bit of `wdc` is 00.?

I may not understand the question. But taking it as is, this is the answer.

The `|` binary OR operator cannot change value of any bit of `wdc` to `0`.

The binary AND `&` can. If your intention is to clear 2 lowest bits, `&` can be used:

```
uintptr_t v = 0;
v = ~v          // v holds 1's
v = v<<2;       // 0's go to the 2 lowest bits

name->value = (void *) ((uintptr_t) wdc & v); // clearing 2 bits.
```

Ofter the question has been edited it looks like we have to check if 2 lower bits of `wdc` are indeed zero before proceeding. This is simple:

```
 if ( (wdc & 0x03) == 0 ) // check if both lower bits of wdc are zero 
  {

  }
```

Ok! Now question is:

> In nginx, a pointer initial by ngx_pcalloc() make sure that the lowest
>   2 bit is 00?

It is already `00`. You do not have to do anything. According to the [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/alloc/)

```
ngx_pcalloc
void *ngx_pcalloc(ngx_pool_t *pool, size_t size)
```

is just a wrapper for `ngx_palloc()` which also sets every byte of the allocation to 0.

Comment: I am sorry, I have  add a example in question, My point is `((uintptr_t)p)&(0x3) == 0` not  `(*p)&(0x3) == 0`.